# Values are getting deleted from the database when the application is run again

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, zk

I have a made a sample application in Spring + Hibernate + ZK framework. 
In the Hibernate configuration file I have kept the property hbm2ddl.auto in "update" mode. Still Whenever I run the application again I dont get the values persisted earlier.

Following are several configuration files for reference:

BeanLocations.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- Database Configuration -->
    <import resource="../database/DataSource.xml"/>
    <import resource="../database/Hibernate.xml"/>

    <!-- Auto scan the components -->
    <context:component-scan 
        base-package="com.nagarro" />

</beans>
```

DataSource.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>properties/database.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value = "${hibernate.current_session_context_class}" /> -->
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Hibernate.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx">

    <!-- Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>

            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>

                <value>com.nagarro.model.ItemAttribute</value>
                <value>com.nagarro.model.ItemAttributeGroup</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Controller/ Viewmodel class

```
public class ItemAttributeRenderer {

    /*
     * The Logger reference variable used for Logging.
     */
    static private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ItemAttributeRenderer.class);

    @Autowired
    private ItemAttributeService itemAttrService;

    private List<ItemAttribute> itemList = new ArrayList<ItemAttribute>();

    private void prepareAndSaveItemAttributeData(){
        ItemAttribute item = null;
        int counter;
        for(int index = 0; index < 5; index++){
            counter = index+1;
            item = new ItemAttribute("Item "+counter, "Attirbute Value"+counter, "Qualifier Value"+counter);
            itemAttrService.save(item);
        }
    }
    /**
     * @return the itemList
     */
    public List<ItemAttribute> getItemList() {
        ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/spring/config/BeanLocations.xml");
        itemAttrService = (ItemAttributeService)appContext.getBean("itemAttrService");
        prepareAndSaveItemAttributeData();
        itemList = itemAttrService.getItemAttributeList();
        return itemList;
    }

    @Command
    public void save(){
        for(ItemAttribute item : itemList){
            itemAttrService.update(item);
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param itemList the itemList to set
     */
    public void setItemList(List<ItemAttribute> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }
    /**
     * @return the itemAttrService
     */
    public ItemAttributeService getItemAttrService() {
        return itemAttrService;
    }
    /**
     * @param itemAttrService the itemAttrService to set
     */

    public void setItemAttrService(ItemAttributeService itemAttrService) {
        this.itemAttrService = itemAttrService;
    }



}
```

View file:

```
<?page title="Result"?>
<zk>
    <custom-attributes center="${arg.center }" />
    <window apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
        viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.nagarro.viewmodel.ItemAttributeRenderer')"
        title="Result Window" border="normal">
        <div>
            <grid>
                <rows>
                    <row>
                        <listbox model="@bind(vm.itemList)">
                            <listhead>
                                <listheader label="Item Name"
                                    style="text-align:center;">
                                </listheader>
                                <listheader label="Attribute Value"
                                    style="text-align:center;">
                                </listheader>
                                <listheader label="Qualifier Value"
                                    style="text-align:center;">
                                </listheader>
                            </listhead>
                            <template name="model" var="item">
                                <listitem value="${item }">
                                    <listcell label="@load(item.name)"
                                        style="text-align:center;">

                                    </listcell>
                                    <listcell style="text-align:center;">
                                    <textbox value="@bind(item.attributeValue)"
                                        style="text-align:center;"/>

                                    </listcell>
                                    <listcell
                                        label="@load(item.qualifierValue)"
                                        style="text-align:center;">
                                    </listcell>
                                </listitem>
                            </template>
                        </listbox>
                    </row>
                </rows>
            </grid>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:right; padding:10px;">
            <button label="Save" mold="trendy"
                onClick="@command('save')">
            </button>

        </div>
    </window>
</zk>
```

Service class

```
@Service("itemAttrService")
public class ItemAttributeServiceImpl implements ItemAttributeService{

    @Autowired
    ItemAttributeDao itemAttrDao;

    public void setItemAttrDao(ItemAttributeDao itemAttrDao) {
        this.itemAttrDao = itemAttrDao;
    }


    public void save(ItemAttribute item){
        itemAttrDao.save(item);

    }

    public void update(ItemAttribute item){
        itemAttrDao.update(item);

    }

    public void delete(ItemAttribute item){
        itemAttrDao.delete(item);
    }

    public ItemAttribute findByItemAttributeName(String name){
        return itemAttrDao.findByItemAttributeName(name);
    }

    public List<ItemAttribute> getItemAttributeList(){
        return itemAttrDao.getItemAttributeList();
    }

}
```

DAO class

```
@Repository("itemAttrDao")
public class ItemAttributeDaoImpl extends CustomHibernateDaoSupport  implements ItemAttributeDao {


    public void save(ItemAttribute itemAttribute) {
        getHibernateTemplate().save(itemAttribute);
        //getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
    }


    public void update(ItemAttribute itemAttribute) {
        getHibernateTemplate().update(itemAttribute);
        //getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
    }


    public void delete(ItemAttribute itemAttribute) {
        getHibernateTemplate().delete(itemAttribute);
        //getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
    }


    public ItemAttribute findByItemAttributeName(String name) {
        List list = getHibernateTemplate().find("from ItemAttribute where name=?",name);
        if(list == null){

        }else if(list.isEmpty()){

        }
        return (ItemAttribute)list.get(0);
    }


    public List<ItemAttribute> getItemAttributeList() {
        List<ItemAttribute> itemList = getHibernateTemplate().find("from ItemAttribute ");
        return itemList;
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ZKSpringHibernateExample</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringHibernateExample</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring framework -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>



                    <!-- MySQL database driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate framework -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate library dependecy end -->

        <!-- ZK Dependency start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zkplus</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zhtml</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zkbind</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zul</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ZK Dependency Ends -->

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My problem is When I run the application again all the data that was saved earlier vanishes even though I have set the hbm2ddl.auto property to update mode.
I have set my show_sql property as "true" to check the queries that are getting fired but there are no delete queries which are getting fired.
Is there any other important thing that I am missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. there were a lot of messy project dependencies in my Tomcat so I deleted that instance of Tomcat and reconfigured it for my project. Then I cleaned my project and now everything is working fine as it should be. Thanks for taking time to post the answers.

Answer (score 0):

See comments and read Hibernate manual [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/)

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

setting above property Drop and re-create the database schema on startup

consider below comments from hibernate manual.

Hibernate's automatic session management for persistence contexts is particularly useful in this context. The hbm2ddl.auto option turns on automatic generation of database schemas directly into the database. This can also be turned off by removing the configuration option, or redirected to a file with the help of the SchemaExport Ant task.

Comment: I commented out the hbm2ddl.auto option from the configuration file but then also the values are getting removed from the database when I run the application again.

Comment: This is strange. Are you sure you have comment code running on your server and there no old code or cached code.

Answer (score 0):

`hbm2ddl.auto` is for the validation of the database schema, which doesn't have any meaning here.

You have to commit your values, if not they are not permanently stored in the database.

Comment: But after stopping the application I check the database again to verify the values. The values were still there but when I run the application again the values are gone and I cant see any delete query in the log.

Comment: Moreover HibernateTemplate provided by the Spring commits the transactions automatically.

This class can be considered as direct alternative to working with the raw Hibernate3 Session API (through SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()). The major advantage is its automatic conversion to DataAccessExceptions as well as its capability to fall back to 'auto-commit' style behavior when used outside of transactions.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html